# Бесплатный хостинг и свой домен

Tags: домен, хостинг

Здравствуйте. Есть ли возможность к бесплатному хостингу купить/привязать домен уникальный? (Не 3-го уровня)

Вот например, hostinger.ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть даже видео, как это делать

[Создание сайта с доменом второго уровня](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbmtKfwR39g).

Answer (score 0):

Это от хостинга зависит. Если они позволяют на бесплатных тарифах прописывать свои `dns` записи, то да. Но мне кажется это редкость.

upd: хотя это тут просто кто-то пиарится ))

Answer (score 0):

есть и бесплатный первого уровня: dot.tk